# Loop error using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im updating my htaccess so I can redirect my .net and .org domains to .com, but but I get a "domain has a loop error".

Im sure the issue has to do with the redirect of non-www to www, but Im not sure how to combine all the code. Any ideas?

My goal is to: (1) Redirect non-www to www (already setup and works perfect)and (2) Redirect .net and .org domains to .com

HTACCESS:

```
##### RewriteEngine enabled - BEGIN
RewriteEngine On

##### RewriteBase set - BEGIN
RewriteBase /

##### Redirect non-www to www - BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

##Redirect .net and .org to .com - BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

NOTE: Both .net and .org domains are ALREADY pointing to the same IP so there is no issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(org|net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava this worked perfect!! clean and concise